# Replace string in php in a file that there is same words

Tags: php, str-replace

I am using this function to replace strings in a file:

```
function replace_in_file($FilePath, $OldText, $NewText)
{
    $Result = array('status' => 'error', 'message' => '');
    if(file_exists($FilePath)===TRUE)
    {
        if(is_writeable($FilePath))
        {
            try
            {
                $FileContent = file_get_contents($FilePath);
                $FileContent = str_replace($OldText, $NewText, $FileContent);
                if(file_put_contents($FilePath, $FileContent) > 0)
                {
                    $Result["status"] = 'success';
                }
                else
                {
                   $Result["message"] = 'Error while writing file';
                }
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                $Result["message"] = 'Error : '.$e;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $Result["message"] = 'File '.$FilePath.' is not writable !';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $Result["message"] = 'File '.$FilePath.' does not exist !';
    }
    return $Result;
}
```

the problem is this: I have a lot of similar words in my file. so when I change one of them all of them changes. what should I do to change only that I want?

myfile.php:

```
define("word1","string");
define("word2","string");
define("word3","string");
...
```

(How to change for example string value in word1 without changing strings in others?)

Comment: It would have helped if you included examples of how it does not work and what you expect it to do instead.

Comment: for example I want to change "string" value of word1, I use function like this: $oldtext = "string"; $newtext = "something new!"; replace_in_file($filepath,$oldtext,$newtext); ............ But when I execute this all of string values changed to "something new!" ! I just want to word1 value's to be changed. I hope this helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple approaches you could take. Two I'll show here rely on the regular data structure you have indicated in your example file contents.

Rather than replacing the term "`string`" you could replace the term `("word1","string")` keeping most of that substring the same but changing only the string portion.

Something like:

```
$fileContents = '
define("word1","string");
define("word2","string");
define("word3","string");
';

$oldText = '("word1","string")';
$newText = '("word1","NewString")';

$fileContents = str_replace($oldText,$newText,$fileContents);

echo $fileContents;
```

Another option is to search for "word1" or another search term, and replace a substring just after it (3 characters after it if your replacement term is separated from your search term by `","`:

```
// File contents based on question text:
$fileContents = '
define("word1","string");
define("word2","string");
define("word3","string");
';

// Word to search for:
$searchWord = 'word1';
// Replacement text for that line:
$newText = "someNewText";


// to determine the length between the search term and the replacement term.
$seperator = '","';


// Get beginning position of the search string
if( $position = strpos($fileContents,$searchWord.$seperator) ) {

    // Where the word to be replaced starts:
    $start = $position + strlen($searchWord.$seperator);

    // length of the term to be replaced:
    $length = strlen("string");

    // do the actual replacements:
    $fileContents = substr_replace($fileContents,$newText,$start,$length);

}

echo $fileContents;
```

I've put both approaches into a php sandbox: [approach 1](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2cd311a19b3f4abcdc0c6cab5867c4e9e280d024), [approach 2](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a6a0d85a5c1d11ee8bd4f91dc5df787df3096a42).

Comment: thank u. I used first solution and it worked very well.